# Need Help : Conversion from string "RS201504170001" to type 'Double' is not valid

Tags: mysql, vb.net

I am trying to make automatic number and got this below error
Please help me to fix it.

Below are the codes I have :

```
 Sub noresep()
    Call Koneksi()
    Dim nors As String = "Select * from tb_resep where no_resep in (Select max(no_resep) from tb_resep)"
    cmd = New MySqlCommand(nors, db)
    dr = cmd.ExecuteReader
    dr.Read()
    If Not dr.HasRows Then
        txt_noresep.Text = "RS" + Format(Now, "yyyyMMdd") + "0001"
    Else
        If Microsoft.VisualBasic.Mid(CStr(dr.Item("no_resep")), 3, 8) <> Format(Now, "yyyyMMdd") Then
            txt_noresep.Text = "RS" + Format(Now, "yyyyMMdd") + "0001"
        Else
            txt_noresep.Text = CDbl(dr.Item("no_resep")) + 1 'Error in this line
        End If
```

Comment: I got error : Conversion from string "RS201504170001" to type 'Double' is not valid.

Comment: "Automatic number" gives no information about what your code is attempting to do at all. Without knowing what purpose the code is supposed to achieve, there's no way anyone could advice on fixing.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well, you just cannot convert letters to a numeric datatype, delete the "RS" part from the string.

```
txt_noresep.Text = CDbl(dr.Item("no_resep").ToString.TrimStart({"R"c, "S"c})).ToString
```

Comment: @Glenn Maramis Glad to help but if its solved then please mark the answer as accepted, welcome to StackOverflow, but read the rules.